# path of packets through network stack

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel

I'm trying to study and understand operations of the Linux tcp/ip stack, specifically how 'ping' sends packets down and receives them.
Ping creates raw socket in AF_INET family, therefore I placed printk in inet_sendmsg() at net/ipv4/af_inet.c to print out the socket protocol name (RAW, UDP etc.) and the address of protocol specific sendmsg function which correctly appears to be raw_sendmsg() from net/ipv4/raw.c

Now, I'm sending a single packet and observe that I'm getting printk form inet_sendmsg() twice.This puzzles me -- is it normal (has something to do with interrupts etc. ?) or there's something broken in the kernel?

Platform - ARM5te, kernel 2.6.31.8

Looking forward to hearing from you !

Mark

Comment: I've written my own client/server processes so that I can identify each socket before its a system call. This way I know exactly what's being called and can trace it down the stack w/o guessing what another client is doing. Of course you can look into the ping source to be absolutely sure of whats going on inside it as well. struct proto callbacks don't fire unless they're called, so verify your client is the one calling twice.

Comment: Can you try to capture the ICMP packets from and to your host? If you only send one packet (ping -c 1), you should see one ICMP echo request and one ICMP echo reply, therefore inet_sendmsg() should be called once.

Comment: Did you do this? Do you have to recompile the kernel after adding printks? Please answer your question if you got it done, I would like to know more.